# Descargar pdf y guardarlo

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando implementar en mi app un código que mire si un pdf está en la carpeta assets y si no lo encuentra lo descargue de un link.

El código es capaz de detectar bien si existe o no un pdf, pero no consigo que lo descargue cuando no lo encuentre en la carpeta assets. Creo que el problema está en la nube y el link que uso de descarga, pero no estoy seguro. Puede ser este el problema? Si es así me podeis recomendar alguna web donde subirlo?

Mi código es este:

```
public void cambio (View view){
        Intent objI = new Intent(aleman.this, visualizador_pdf.class);

        File fichero = new File("app/src/main/assets/aleman.pdf");

        if(!fichero.exists()){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id= 1hfTydBhbqC3hq59U_5jAXEhJcRWuYFPU");
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app/src/main/assets";
                Log.v("PdfManager", "PATH: " + Path);
                File file = new File(Path);
                file.mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("aleman.pdf");

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[702];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("PdfManager", "Error: " + e);
            }
            Log.v("PdfManager", "Check: ");
        }
        objI.putExtra("datos", "aleman.pdf");
        startActivity(objI);
    }
```

Saludos y gracias

Actualización: he probado con drive (que permite generar links con descarga directa) pero sigue sin funcionar.

No me da ningún error pero la primera vez que lo ejecuto no funciona y la segunda crashea la app.

Puede ser que el problema este en el directorio? app/src/main/assets/

Comment: Quizas te valga la API que indican [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812683/download-files-from-mega-co-nz-in-java)

Comment: Pinta bien la Api, lo que no me queda claro es como importarla a mi proyecto @Cadeq

Comment: @Gorpe que problema se indica en el LogCat cuando intentas la descarga, es importante saber esta información.

Comment: No me sale ningún error en el LogCat, he probado a usar drive en lugar de mega, pero no consigo que descargue y guarde el pdf @Jorgesys

Comment: Quieres descargar en : app/src/main/assets/ ??? @Gorpe

Comment: Si, he probado en varios directorios diferentes pero no consigo que funcione en ninguno @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas un Get a la Url que estas poniendo te descarga el html de la pagina:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="MEGA" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="MEGA provides free cloud storage with convenient and powerful always-on privacy. Claim your free 50GB now" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://mega.nz/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cms2.mega.nz/5b342017f1b709b7098b4567.png" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="MEGA" />
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="MEGA provides free cloud storage with convenient and powerful always-on privacy. Claim your free 50GB now" />
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://mega.nz/" />
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://cms2.mega.nz/5b342017f1b709b7098b4567.png" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html, charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://mega.nz/favicon.ico?v=3" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigefpfhnfcobdlfbedofhhaibnlghod" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=706857885"/>
    <meta name="description" content="MEGA provides free cloud storage with convenient and powerful always-on privacy. Claim your free 50GB now!" />
    <title>MEGA</title>
</head>
<body id="bodyel">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/secureboot.js?r=1566953874" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div id="overlay" style="display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0px; right:0px; cursor:wait; z-index:999999;"></div>
    <div class="download-overlay" id="download_overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="nav-overlay hidden"></div>
    <div id="pageholder" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="startholder" class="fmholder"></div>
    <div id="fmholder" class="fmholder" style="display:none;"></div>
    <a href="" download="filename" id="dllink" style="display:none;"></a>
    <div style="position:absolute;" id="startswfdiv"></div>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; width:100%; top:0px; height:60px; z-index:99; display:none;" id="topmenufm"></div>
    <div id="popnotifications"></div>
    <textarea id="chromeclipboard" title="copy" style="position:absolute;top:-100%;left:-100%;opacity:0"></textarea>
</body>
```

Si quieres descargar el archivo deberías parsear o buscar un cliente que te facilite el trabajo. Independientemente podrías utilizar xamp y algún servidor gratuito de internet y dejarte de problemas con mega.

hay algunos clientes para trabajar con mega:

[aquí tienes uno que solo tienes que descargarte el src con los .java añadirlo a tu proyecto, importar la clases a tu clase y seguir los pasos que pone en el README.md](https://github.com/Ale46/Mega-Java)

[y este que me lo recomendaron pero nunca lo llegue a probar https://github.com/meganz/android](https://github.com/meganz/android)

Comment: Esto no tienes que ver en el problema, puedes notar en la pregunta que esta definiendo un url cifrado: https://

Comment: quería ponerlo como comentario, pero no me deja. No había visto la s, ya he corregido la respuesta.

Comment: Y podria hacer un get sobre esta url? https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id= 1hfTydBhbqC3hq59U_5jAXEhJcRWuYFPU @LuisDominguez

Comment: con drive hay una api de google https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads .  Siguiendo los pasos que ponen tendrías que poder descargarlo.